# Application design - Updating domain object

Tags: java, swing, architecture, network-programming

I would like to improve the design of some part of my application.  It is a swing application in which the user interface is updated by data received from a server (TCP/UDP).  At the moment i pass my domain object (POJO) to the constructor of the class the will connect with the server, receive and send data, and directly use getter and setter method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port, domainModel);
}

public class TcpClient {
public void connect() {
// Code to create the socket and connect to the server.

new Thread(new TcpProtocol(socket, domainModel)).start();
}
}
```

I 'm using some sort of Factory class inside the TcpProtocol class to create the right object.
I would like to decouple my domain object from the network programming part.  Is there some common pattern to use for this ?  I was thinking about DAO and Value Object, commonly used for JavaEE applications.  Those are the only one i see, but if someone has better proposition please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule I consider non-trivial code in the constructor to be a design smell since it complicates inheritance and other forms of extensibility.

If you do not need the object to update itself from the network after it is created, then you can use a `Factory` to create your `POJO`.  I tend to avoid `ValueObjects` unless you are wrapping something with very little data like currency/dates otherwise you will end up with a bunch of getters/setters.

If you need the object to access the network during its use, then you can make it a `Proxy` and pass in a `DAO` that handles all the network code.  For testing you pass in a `Mock/Stub` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A start to reaching your goal would be to remove the network access code from your constructor (I'm assuming you have one class that contacts the network and you're passing your POJO to its constructor). You would instead create a utility that contacts the network.

To instantiate the correct object type from your data stream, you might consider creating a `Factory` that knows how to adapt the stream to specific object types.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the java.io ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream might be a simple way to do this since it does not depend on the class of the object transferred?

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest to do is apply the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern. You might also need to apply the [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern along with your Observer - but check carefully if your design 
warrants this kind of complexity.

The idea behind the observer is that your UI code "listens" for changes in the presented model. When changes take place (presumably from your network-bound code) an event is fired and your UI is thus notified in order to update itself accordingly,